# How to print JSON to C# in nancy

Tags: c#, json, nancy

I have a `.json` file is called `file.json`. I'd like to print on a screen the data like name and age that JSON file has when the URL is `localhost:8080/data`. Here's what I tried and it gets me an error below on web page 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NancyWinForm.MainMod+Item]

```
  Get["/data"] = x =>
            {
               return LoadJson();
            };        
        }
        public string LoadJson()
        {
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json");
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
            String items2 = items.ToString();
            return items2;

        }
        public class Item
        {
            public int age;
            public string name;

        }
```

Comment: So, what does or doesn't this do?

Comment: gives an error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NancyWinForm.MainMod+Item]

Comment: Why don't you just `return json;`?

Comment: I guess, it doesn't give an error, but it just converts an object to a string, but you expect it to be done other way (f.i., to be serialized).

Comment: Some other very important things to mention and to be reviewed and investigated by you: use properties, follow C# naming guidelines, dispose `StreamReader` with `using` syntactic sugar, maintain vertical and horizontal spacing to make your code readable to yourself and others.

Comment: Btw: It does not given an error. Its prints the same as `Console.WriteLine(new List<Item>());` - just the `ToString` method of a `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are after something like:

```
public string LoadJson()
{
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json");
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
    return string.Join("\r\n", items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
}

public class Item
{
    public int age;
    public string name;

    public override string ToString() => $"Age: {age}, Name: {name}";
}
```

The changes I've made are as following:

1. Implemented the `ToString` method to present the `Item` class in method
2. In the `LoadJson` method, returned a joined string for all the results of the `ToString` method for each item in the list

If what you wanted instead was to display the JSON format, you could us JSON serialize or actually just display the content of the file as is :)

Also I recommend to follow the C# convention and use PascalCasing to name public properties in `Item` and tag it with the name of the corresponding tags.

Comment: thanks very much :) but how can I print these datas line by line ?

Comment: Do you mean show them separated by a line break? If you are going to display in an HTML straight away, you can `return string.Join("<br/>", ` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: Although I prefer returning the list, and bind the list with a web control that show a list of items

Comment: Here is an example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/77a82c/binding-gridview-using-list-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to deserialize your file content and then convert it back to an json using `ToString()` This will also not serialize your list in a json string.

Instead try the following:

```
Get["/data", true] = async (param, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        string json;
        try
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.json"))
            {
                json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                // if you want to project your data into another form you 
                // can do this, as @Bishoy suggested
                var itemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
                json = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                         itemList.Select(x => $"Age:{x.Age}, Name: {x.Name}"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        return json;
    };
```